# Cannot write schema.gql to Google's App Engine at runtime NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, graphql, nestjs

I am using NestJS and I am using their graphql package.

https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql

Nest Generates the schema.gql file at run time. This is causing an issue with google's App Engine because by default, applications can't write to the file system.

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'schema.gql'`

I understand how this would be a problem for storing data on the file system, but this schema.gql file that is generated at runtime is nessecary for the app to run and doesn't matter if it gets replicated.

Is there a work around I am missing? Can I get this to generate serverside somehow? Or is there a way I could make it apart of compile time when the application builds?

Any help is appriciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Shout out to the NestJS Discord where this question got answered by @TreeMan360!

Where you have:

```
autoSchemaFile
```

in your

```
GraphqQLModule.forRoot({...
```

set it to:

```
true
```

which gives you an  automatic, in memory only, schema. I do this like so:

```
GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      autoSchemaFile: isLocalEnvironment() ? 'api-public.schema.gql' : true,
      playground: !isProductionEnvironment(), ...
```

Following these instructions solved my problem! Niffty huh?